# Language change with KeyDown event on all Form

Tags: c#

I develop an application that can change language between english and hungarian. This software work with `.resx` files and when the user presses <kbd>F2</kbd> the Labels, Buttons, and other controls their `Text` properties will be changed from the .resx file.

It's ok, but when I have more than one Form open, naturally the `KeyDown` event changes those controls that are in the focused Form. So my question is: how can I capture the <kbd>F2</kbd> keystroke in all opened Forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: Based on clues in your question I am assuming Winforms rather than WPF:

`how can I capture the F2 keystroke in all opened Forms?` You can't, not without some ridiculously complicated code. The closest you can come is by re-dispatching events in one Form to other forms. In any case, you need a way to track your open windows and when an F2 key is hit in any of them you need to tell all of your open forms to change the language.

Somewhere in your application where you create new forms you need a collection like `List<Form>` for example that will hold your list of existing forms. (You can also try and use built-in collections in your Control objects) Whenever you create a new form, you add to this collection, when one closes you should remove it. And when any of those forms captures an <kbd>F2</kbd> key then you loop through the collection telling each one to switch its language.

This would be a great place for you to inherit from the Form class and add your own properties and methods to make the behavior uniform across all of your forms.

Here is an [example article that uses delegates](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mosessaur/winformsdelegates09042006094826AM/winformsdelegates.aspx) for inter-form communication.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use Events to implement this. I don't know which technology you are using. WinForms or WPF.

IF you are developing this functionality in a WPF technology with MVVM then you could have declared 'SelectedLanguage' property in a Class lets say 'Langugage' implementing INotifyPropertyChanged interface. Derive your other view models with this class and then on 'SelectedLanguage' propertyChanged event you can notify each and every view model about the change of language on which you can have a method to read resource files and change values of UI.

May be I am out of context with respect to technology. But Events mechanism or Observer Pattern will resolve your problems.